# 15mm thru axle to quick release

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, quick-release, through-axle

I bought a set of 29" Shimano Deore XT wheels (WH-M785). The front wheel has a 15mm thru axle, whereas the read wheel has a normal quick release.
Installing the rear wheel on my bike (Trek 8.6 DS 2016) is no problem, but the front wheel is. The current wheel I have uses a quick release and 15mm thru axles won't fit in the Suntour fork (NRX D-DS-RL-COIL 700C TS 265/0).
So I want to ask if this combination of additional parts will allow me to install the front wheel:

- http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/be/en/nukeproof-conversion-kit-15mm-to-qr/rp-prod80192
- https://www.bike24.com/1.php?content=8;product=4679 (100mm front wheel version)

I'm a bit worried about the difference between 5mm and 9mm quick release. The conversion kit is for 9mm QR, but I'm not sure the Deore XT qr I'm getting is 5mm or 9mm.

Answer (score 2):

Those kits will definitely work. That skewer is a 9mm. The skewer is also 5mm because that's the measurement of a 9mm skewer in the center of the skewer.